# is it wrong to call a method outside main()

Tags: c++

I was wondering if someone could explain the meaning of the following error:

**CODE**

```
    #include "sstream"

    std::stringstream h;

    h.str(""); //clearing the stringstream object

    int main()
```

**ERROR**

> kial.cpp:5:1: error: ‘h’ does not name a type  h.str("");

Also why is it wrong to try to access the method ouside of the main()?

Comment: because that's not how C++ works. The program flow is defined within main. Everything else is defining stuff which main can use (functions, global variables, etc).

Comment: An exception to the answers - you can create a global object whose constructor will be called. In this case, you call a constructor as stringstream h(""). However, a stringstream begins empty so this is not required.

Comment: @NeilKirk Mind dumbing it down a bit,sir?

Comment: h is a global variable, created with its default constructor. You could replace it with std::stringstream h("hello"); to begin with this text in h, even outside of main.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so everyone landed here with a simple statement saying that you cannot do it. Trust no one. In fact, you can. But not like you have tried to do it. Generally, you cannot have statements like function calls outside other functions. And the first function to get called is always `main`. However, C++ has [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and global objects. Therefore, there is only one exception to the above rule - construction and destruction of global objects. By employing [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and declaring some object global, you can have its constructor called, and do the rest from there. So for example, you could solve you problem like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream> // just for std::cout and std::endl.

std::stringstream h;

struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct() {
        h.str(""); //clearing the stringstream object
        std::cout << "`h` string stream is cleared now!" << std::endl;
    }
};

MyStruct mystruct;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "I am called AFTER MyStruct's constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++98 ./test.cc  && ./test
`h` string stream is cleared now!
I am called AFTER MyStruct's constructor
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: I have to ask , why the pedantic flag?

Comment: @nerorevenge: Ah, just a pathological habit, nothing serious. Just like to see all the warning I can get, so usually throw in pedantic, `-Wextra` etc.

Comment: Well I'm going to make that a habit now.

Comment: @nerorevenge it's also a good thing to show when doing an example like this, demonstrating that the author knows he's abiding by the standard and not exploiting some gnu extension

Comment: Warning: This works within a single file, because globals from a single source file are created in file order. Here, `h` appears before `mystruct` so it's created earlier. But globals from different files are not created in any particular order.

Comment: @MSalters: You are right indeed. Global variables are problematic when it comes to order, different translation units and static libraries. Though in this particular case it is all good.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is assuming you tried to make a declaration (or a definition), since general statements are not allowed at global scope.

The short answer to why this is not allowed is that the standard says so.

To think through why that is the answer, consider when you would expect the code to execute. What does it mean to call a function at global (or namespace) scope, given the already-defined order of execution of a program?

If you really have something you need to do at that scope, you can always use an instance of a class whose constructor does what you want.